# Group WPF DataGrid expander

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, grouping

I would like to regroup all `ClassMate` of same `GroupName` with an expander...

```
<DataGrid x:Name="gridMates" ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}">
```

With `BindingGroup`s.
These groups are composed by:

```
public class Group
{ 
    public List<ClassMate> CLGroup { get; set; }
    public string GroupName { get; set; }
}
```

My `ClassMate` class is:

```
public class ClassMate: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }}
```

My XAML is:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="gridMates"  ItemsSource="{Binding Groups }"  >
        <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
            <!-- Style for groups at top level. -->
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                    <Expander IsExpanded="True" >
                                        <Expander.Header>
                                            <DockPanel>

                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=GroupName}" />
                                        </DockPanel>
                                        </Expander.Header>
                                        <Expander.Content>
                                            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CLGroup}">
                                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                                    <DataTemplate>
                                                        <StackPanel>
                                                            <TextBlock   Text="{Binding Path=DisplayName}"/>

                                                        </StackPanel>

                                                    </DataTemplate>
                                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                            </ItemsControl>
                                        </Expander.Content>
                                    </Expander>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            </GroupStyle>

        </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
```

I tried in this way, but doesn't works.
How to regroup them? Could you help me?
Thanks

Comment: Do you want to use maybe a TreeView? TreeView has native support for expander control, and you can define your group classes with child classmates. Please read an example here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/124644/Basic-Understanding-of-Tree-View-in-WPF

Comment: I prefer to use dataGrid. Thx anyway